# Using David Bradshaw's iFrameResize

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm asking help on how to use David Bradshaw's iframe resizer? I'm planning to use it on blogger, because I'm using an iframe to show crossdomain contents, I want the iframe to resize depending on its content's size.

**Here's what I did to my blogger blog template, I've added this above `</body>` tag:**

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('iframe').iFrameSizer({
// Disable if using size method with custom dimensions.
autoResize                : true,

// Override the body background style in the iFrame.
bodyBackground            : null,

// Override the default body margin style in the iFrame.
// A string can be any valid value for the CSS margin attribute, 
// for example '8px 3em'. A number value is converted into px.
bodyMargin                : null,
bodyMarginV1              : 8,
bodyPadding               : null,

// When set to true, only allow incoming messages from the domain 
// listed in the src property of the iFrame tag. If your iFrame 
// navigates between different domains, ports or protocols; 
// then you will need to disable this option.
checkOrigin               : true,

// If enabled, a window.parentIFrame object is created in the iFrame 
// that contains methods outlined
enablePublicMethods       : false,

// 'bodyOffset' | 'body<a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Scroll/">Scroll</a>' | 'documentElementOffset' | 'documentElementScroll' | 
// 'max' | 'min' | 'grow' | 'lowestElement'
heightCalculationMethod   : 'offset',

// The default value is equal to two frame refreshes at 60Hz
interval                  : 32,

// Setting the log option to true will make the scripts in both the host page 
// and the iFrame output everything they do to the JavaScript console 
// so you can see the communication between the two scripts.
log                       : false,

// Set maximum height/width of iFrame.
maxHeight                 : Infinity,
maxWidth                  : Infinity,

// Set minimum height/width of iFrame.
minHeight                 : 0,
minWidth                  : 0,

// Enable scroll bars in iFrame.
scrolling                 : false,

// Resize iFrame to content height.
sizeHeight                : true,

// Resize iFrame to content width.
sizeWidth                 : false,

// Set the number of pixels the iFrame content size has to change by, 
// before triggering resize of the iFrame.
tolerance                 : 0,

// Called when iFrame is closed via parentIFrame.close() method.
closedCallback            : function(){},

// Initial setup callback function.
initCallback              : function(){},

// Receive message posted from iFrame with the parentIFrame.sendMessage() method.
messageCallback           : function(){},

// Function called after iFrame resized.
resizedCallback           : function(){},

// Called before the page is repositioned after a request from the iFrame
scrollCallback            : function(){return true;}
});
</script>
  <script src='http://javascript.ext/system/iframeResizer.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

**And I've added this above my crossdomain page's `</body>` tag:**

```js
<script src="./system/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
<script src="./system/jquery.js"></script>
```

**But nothing happens, the iframe is not auto resizing :( Can anyone help me?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the scripts in the blogger page. The `iframeResizer.min.js` is required to set up the iframe so it needs to be first.

Also there seems to be a typo with the invocation. It should be:

```
$('iframe').iFrameResize({ /* options */ });
```

This only works if you have jQuery on your page. If you don't have it you should be able to setup you iframe like this:

```
iFrameResize({ /* options */ }, 'iframe');
```

Where `iframe` is the css selector.